# How to access multiple environments in Symfony without editing htaccess?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Symfony seems to provide an easy way to have different development setups and comes in with production and development environment templates by default - ones that can be accessed by accessing app.php and app_dev.php respectively.  They also seem to pick the appropriate config files.

I am trying to create my own environment, so I have created app_dev_local.php and have also created config_dev_local.xml. However, there is no way for me to specify that my front controller is app_dev_local.php anywhere apart from the htaccess file. The trouble is this htaccess file is under source control, hence I can't really edit it. Does it mean I can't have an environment of my own different to that of my team mates? Or have I gotten everything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we solved it:

In conf.d directory of /etc/httpd:
File: application.conf

```
Alias /application/debug  /var/www/symfony/application/debug/
Alias /application/dev    /var/www/symfony/application/dev/
Alias /application/test   /var/www/symfony/application/test/
Alias /application        /var/www/symfony/application/web/


<Directory "/var/www/symfony/application/web">
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/app.php [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/symfony/application/debug/">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/debug/debug.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/symfony/application/dev/">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/dev/dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/symfony/application/test/">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/test/test.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And then in the root application directory

```
ln -s web test
ln -s web debug
ln -s web dev
```

And then in application/web

make a custom test.php, debug.php, or dev.php for your needs (we've renamed app_dev.php to dev.php in our shop).

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to easily develop a number of sites locally, commit to source control, deploy to the production server, and have them operate in production mode automatically.  Thankfully there's not a whole lot of difference between app.php and app_dev.php, so we just merged the two files, and used an environment variable to set the environment. The resulting file ends up looking like the below:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// get our web environment from an environment variable
$env = getenv('environment');

$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

if( $env == 'prod' )
{
    // Possibly add APC caching here
}
if( $env == 'dev' )
{
    Debug::enable();
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```